# How to fix: Invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266

I'm trying to upload the code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RuiSantosdotme/Random-Nerd-Tutorials/master/Projects/ESP32/web_server_outputs.ino) to work with an ESP8266. So I copy/pasted the code to the Arduino IDE and I get this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi\src/WiFi.h:79:9: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'int WiFiClass::begin(char*, const char*)' [-fpermissive]
>
> int begin(char* ssid, const char *passphrase);
>          ^
>
> exit status 1
>   invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `begin()` method expects a modifiable character array as its first argument. That's what you should provide:

```cpp
char ssid[]           = "YOUR_SSID";      // this is changed
const char* password  = "YOUR_PASSWORD";  // this is fine
[...]
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
```

Comment: When I try to upload it I get: warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed. Do you know if it is from the code?

Comment: @Physther: I don't know. It's ESP specific and I have no experience with those devices. But see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2801)

Comment: Regarding the `espcomm_sync failed` error, see https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/faq/a01-espcomm_sync-failed.rst

Comment: It's more likely that the WiFi library is simply unwise in its declaration.  There's no real need for the ssid argument to be mutable - the ssid and passphrase are in fact treated identically internally.

Answer (score 2):

The location where you are calling the function begin, has as first parameter a parameter of type const char* instead of char* ... remove the const from this argument type.

Probably you have something like

```
const char* s = ....

...

...begin(s, ...)
```

Change class s to

```
char* s = ...
```

Comment: The same question as for Edgar. Can this: warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed be caused by the code?

Comment: It could be ... I have also no experience with them like Edgar Bonet. Trace back where you call the function that fails and check the parameter values (and compare it to examples).